# How to loop through has_many collection and setup a HABTM with another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have Orders which has many LineItems.  LineItems has_many Leads.  Leads aren't associated to a User until a User purchases them.  The association is setup through a HABTM relationship and a join table LeadsUsers.

Once a User purchases a lead I need to setup the association.  I have a LeadsUsers model with the right HABTM code setup.  In my order model I have the following:

```
has_many :line_items
after_save :assign_lead_to_user

def assign_lead_to_user
   self.line_items.each do 
     leads_users = LeadsUsers.create :user_id => :user_id, :lead_id => line_item.lead.id
     leads_users.save
   end   
  end
```

This method fails: undefined local variable or method `line_item'.  I know this means that it doesn't know what line_item I am referring to... Any ideas?  Ultimately I want to be able to reference User.leads.all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a short look, you need to provide a block variable:

```
self.line_items.each do |line_item|
```